# Mixed Dirichlet-Neumann eigenvalue problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^2$ be a bounded $C^2$ domain. Let $\partial\Omega=\partial\Omega_1\cup\partial\Omega_2$. Does anyone know about the existence of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for the following mixed eigenvalue problem:
$\left\{\begin{array}{l l}-\Delta u=\lambda u&\quad x\in\Omega\\
u=0&\quad x\in\partial\Omega_1\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0&\quad x\in\partial\Omega_2 \end{array}\right.$

Comment: related: [Eigenvalues of the 1D laplacian with mixed boundary conditions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138975/eigenvalues-of-the-1d-laplacian-with-mixed-boundary-conditions)

Comment: @Surb, I think the 1D version is quite different, do you know anything about the $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^n$ case?

Comment: To be honest I forgot almost everything I knew about PDE... However I believe that searching a bit on [google scholar](https://scholar.google.de/) you should find a few paper dealing with this problem.

Comment: I remember that met such problems in the literature while I was looking for the eigenvalues of the $p$-Laplace operator.

Comment: The decomposition of $\partial\Omega$ should probably be a smooth one. And $\partial\Omega_1$ should be non-trivial; otherwise constant functions are a problem. With the correct conditions of this type, what have you done toward showing that $-\Delta$ is (essentially) selfadjoint on a domain of functions satisfying the boundary conditions?

Comment: @TrialAndError I believe integrating by parts and considering the space $C^\infty_c(\Omega\cup\partial\Omega_2)$ would be sufficient?

Comment: Searching for "Zaremba eigenproblem" would be a start: e.g., http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0071.pdf